# How to fix "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when using "dr=webdriver.phantomjs()"?

Tags: python

How could I solve this worng ?

C:\WINDOWS\system32>phantomjs
phantomjs> ^C

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> dr=webdriver.phantomjs()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

>>> driver =
webdriver.phantomjs(executable_path='D:\soft\foldsoft\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantojs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capitalize PhantomJS

```
dr= webdriver.PhantomJS()
```